# IIS: Publish directories by username on IIS WebDAV

Tags: iis, webdav

We need to publish some network directories via WebDAV on our internal network for some mobile devices (mainly iPads).

The intended layout is something like:

http://webdav/username/ points to D:\homes\username (names & paths changed)

So far we have access to the webroot working and logging in with domain credentials works fine as well. We just need to provide access by username now.

Short of creating a WebDAV rule for every possible username, is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: What version of IIS are you working with?

Comment: @Evan: We're using IIS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to become familiar with [AppCmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/352/how-to-configure-webdav-settings-using-appcmd/). You can use it to script configuring WebDAV authoring rules, etc. I haven't done what you're doing (yet-- it's something one Customer and I have talked about for their iPad devices, specifically) but that's the track I'd start down.